# XSLT On Non-Standard XML

Tags: xml

I have been searching everywhere, but keep coming up with errors. I have this xml file:

```
<vmix>
<version>16.0.0.71</version>
<inputs>
<input key="38213dcd-5542-4440-9519-7288efebdd3b" number="1" type="Xaml"     title="ScoreBoardHD.xaml" state="Paused" position="0" duration="0" loop="False"     selectedIndex="0">
ScoreBoardHD.xaml
<text index="0" name="HomeTitle">yyyyyyyyyyyyy</text>
<text index="1" name="AwayTitle">Azzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</text>
<text index="2" name="HomeScore">15</text>
<text index="3" name="AwayScore">2</text>
</input>
<input key="3873bbce-dc0f-4afd-a50b-3e60e74e7d57" number="2" type="Blank"     title="Blank" state="Paused" position="0" duration="0"    loop="False">Blank</input>
</inputs>
<overlays>
<overlay number="1"/>
<overlay number="2"/>
<overlay number="3"/>
<overlay number="4"/>
<overlay number="5"/>
<overlay number="6"/>
</overlays>
<preview>1</preview>
<active>1</active>
<fadeToBlack>False</fadeToBlack>
<transitions>
<transition number="1" effect="Fade" duration="500"/>
<transition number="2" effect="Merge" duration="1000"/>
<transition number="3" effect="Wipe" duration="1000"/>
<transition number="4" effect="CubeZoom" duration="1000"/>
</transitions>
<recording>False</recording>
<external>False</external>
<streaming>False</streaming>
<playList>False</playList>
<multiCorder>False</multiCorder>
<audio>
<master volume="100" muted="False" headphonesVolume="100"/>  
</audio>
</vmix>
```

I am trying to extract this:

```
<text index="0" name="HomeTitle">yyyyyyyyyyyyy</text>
<text index="1" name="AwayTitle">Azzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</text>
<text index="2" name="HomeScore">15</text>
<text index="3" name="AwayScore">2</text>
```

But cannot form in a way that XSLT can parse because the the XML appears to be Non Standard.

```
 <xsl:for-each select="inputs/input/text">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="HomeTitle"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="HomeScore"/></td>
  </tr>
```

Comes up empty. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's not valid xml period... you can only expect to process _valid_ xml.  Is that exactly the text you have? It looks like the last three lines are duplicated.

Comment: Thanks-- I corrected it. Its a settings file from a Video editing program and I am trying to get the text used on titles. Is there any way to get the tags out of the file?

Answer (score 0):

xsltproc seems to handle the XML just fine, but it's fairly lenient after all. The following XSLT produces "`<tr><td>yyyyyyyyyyyyy</td><td>15</td></tr>`" which is what you wanted?

```
<xsl:template match="//inputs/input">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="text[@name='HomeTitle']" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="text[@name='HomeScore']" /></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @columbuscountyschool glad I could help! Don't forget to press the green checkmark to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing "non standard" about your XML (in its current version). Your expression `select="HomeTitle"` in the context of `inputs/input/text/` selects nothing because `HomeTitle` is the value of an attribute, not the name of a child element. So you need to select it with `text[@name='HomeTitle']`.